# Appending address array through assembly

Tags: solidity, assembly

I have an assembly part which creates an address which I want to append to an array in an address => address[] mapping. The code works if I use push() but I am trying to reduce gas usage and have the addition to the array happen in assembly part.

```
function addAddress(address _user) external {
    address result;
    assembly {
        let address := mload(0x40)
        ...
        result := create(0, address, 0x37)
    }
    addressList[_user].push(result);
}
```

I have tried a lot of variations of

```
let length := mload(arr)
length := add(length, 1)
mstore(arr, length)
mstore(add(arr, mul(length, 0x14)), result)
```

but it either makes me revert, oog or later part of script doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `addressList` is defined as such :

```
mapping(address => address[]) public addressList;
```

To do so in assembly only you need to be away of the way [mappings and arrays](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays) are represented in storage.

I beleive that the following code does what you want :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract Test {

    mapping(address => address[]) public addressList;

    function addAddress(address _user) external {
        address result;
        
        assembly {

            // Compue the storage slot of addressList[user]
            // equivalent to keccak256(abi.encode(user, 0))
            // the second parameter is 0 because addressList is
            // declared at storage slot 0
            mstore(0x00, _user)
            mstore(0x20, 0)
            let arraySlot := keccak256(0x00, 0x40)

            // Create the contract
            result := create(0, 0x00, 0x00)

            // Read addressList[user] size
            let arraySize := sload(arraySlot)


            // Compute the storage slot where the data of addresList[user] starts
            // equivalent to keccak256(abi.encode(arraySlot))
            mstore(0x00, arraySlot)
            let dataSlot := keccak256(0x00, 0x20)

            sstore(add(dataSlot, arraySize), result)

            // Increment addressList[user] size
            sstore(arraySlot, add(arraySize, 1))

        }
    }
}
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @hroussille . Works as I wanted. I have added a for loop into the assembly part and was wondering if there is anything inefficient in it.

```
assembly{
            mstore(0x00, sender)
            mstore(0x20, 0)

            let arraySlot := keccak256(0x00, 0x40)
            let arraySize := sload(arraySlot)

            // Cloning contract
            let clone := mload(0x40)
            mstore(clone,0x3d602d80600a3d3981f3363d3d373d3d3d363d73000000000000000000000000)
            mstore(add(clone, 0x14), targetBytes)
            mstore(add(clone, 0x28),0x5af43d82803e903d91602b57fd5bf30000000000000000000000000000000000)

            for {let i := 0} lt(i, _amount) {i := add(i,1)}{
                // create contract to append
                result := create(0, clone, 0x37)

                mstore(0x00, arraySlot)
                sstore(add(keccak256(0x00, 0x20), arraySize), result)
                sstore(arraySlot, add(arraySize, 1))

                arraySize := add(arraySize, 1)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Cannot really try it right now, but it seems to me like you only need to compute the array data slot once, no need to do it in every loop as the initial storage offset is the same.